# React wysiwyg with hastag/user autocomplete & document support

Tags: reactjs, editor, wysiwyg

I have need of a wysiwyg that can do images, with aouto tagging of users ala "@" then it shows list when start typing, so I can select.

I also need users to be able to use pdfs/txt files, maybe excel..with images.

I'm assuming they'd come with callback, I upload the doc type, get response, then display an image (with name) that I have to match with doc type..ie pdf, txt etc.. images would show, as I would be returned a path to a smaller version from my backend.

But, anyone explain the process of how this can work?

Draft.js, tinyMCE, seem to have some of these..but I must host the the files.

Thoughts on editors? I sorta need what Jira provides.